# Find the shortest side if

Tags: triangles

In the $\triangle PQR$     angle P= 60 degrees & angle Q= 90 degrees . Find the length of the shortest side.

Any Ideas on how to begin

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 30-60-90 triangle, so if the length of the shortest side (opposite 30 degrees angle) is x, the side opposite the 60 degree angle is  $\sqrt{3} x$ and and the hypotenuse (side opposite the 90 degree angle) is $2 x$.

You will need one of the side lengths (and know it is for the shortest/ longest leg or hypotenuse) in order to compute $x$ (which gives you the other two side lengths).

Pictorially (from [here](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/30-60-90-triangles.html)):

[image]

Comment: No none of the sides are given :)

Comment: Then all you can say is what the sides are in terms of a given side and what angle they're opposite to, as in the picture above.